# DeviceToken as anonymous identifier IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, devicetoken

Can I use the **DeviceToken** to register user in my server but not for push notification service.

Is it possible to fetch **DevToken** without using push notification delegate method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use device token to register user because if you delete the app & re-install it again then it will give you the same device-token same as previous.

code:

```
  NSString *Device_id=[[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]UUIDString];
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The vendor ID will not be the same if you delete the app and reinstall it. It'll be a new one. The vendor ID remains the same until the _last_ application of the vendor removed. Please see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-SW49

Comment: "The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them." (Source: Apple's documentation)

Comment: @Krumelur, How can we know who is the Vendor of this app?

Comment: If your app's bundle id is "com.yourcompany.someapp", the vendor is "com.yourcompany".

Comment: @Krumelur, yes so , then generally BundleID is not changed & you will get the same vendor. So, you can use the DeviceID from Vendor for a app to register user.

Comment: If your app ids are com.company.app1 and com.company.app2 and you delete app1 and reinstall it, you'll get the same vendor ID. If you delete both apps and install app1 again, the vendor ID will have changed.